# Can a product of a number and its reverse consist of only $1$'s?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

**Problem:**

> Let $n \gt 1$. If you write the digits of $n$ in reverse, then multiply by original $n$, is it possible for the product to consist only of $1$'s?

This came from a competition I recently did, and I found this question quite interesting. Below is the proof I submitted. It's a little tedious in the middle, so feel free to correct any errors.

**Proof:** Let $\bullet n$ denote reversed $n$.

Assume $n$ has $k$-digits. Then

$$n = 10^{k-1}a_1+10^{k-2}a_2 + \dots + 10a_{k-1}+a_k$$

where $0 \le a \le 9$, $a \in \mathbb Z$, and $a$ is the digit. $\bullet n$ multiplied by $n$:

\begin{align}
& \bullet n \cdot n \\
& = (10^{k-1}a_k + 10^{k-2}a_{k-1} + \dots)(10^{k-1}a_1+10^{k-2}a_2 + \dots) \\
& = 10^{2k-2}a_ka_1 + 10^{2k-3}a_ka_2 + 10^{2k-3}a_{k-1}a_1+\dots+10^{2k-k}a_1^2+10^{2k-k}a_2^2+\dots \\
& = 10^{2k-2}(a_ka_1) + 10^{2k-3}(a_ka_2 + a_{k-1}a_1)+\dots + 10^{k}(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \dots ) + \dots \\
\end{align}

We now have the digits of the product of $\bullet n$ and $n$. Equate all digits to $1$:

\begin{align}
1 & = a_ka_1 \tag{1} \\
1 & = a_ka_2 + a_{k-1}a_1 \tag{2} \\
1 & = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \dots + a_{k-1}^2 + a_k^2 \tag{3} \\
\end{align}

Observe $(1)$. $a_ka_1 = 1 \implies a_k = a_1 = 1$. Now observe $(3)$. We have:

\begin{align}
a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \dots + a_{k-1}^2 + a_k^2 & = 1 \tag{3} \\
1^2 + a_2^2 + \dots + a_{k-1}^2 + 1^2 & = 1 \\
a_2^2 + a_3^2 + \dots + a_{k-2}^2 + a_{k-1}^2 & = -1 \\
\end{align}

The sum of the squares of real, positive integers cannot be a negative number. Hence, we have a contradiction. By *reductio ad absurdum*, we have proved that the product of $n$ and $\bullet n$ cannot consist only of $1$'s. $\Box$

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: This is wrong.  You didn't take carries into account.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That's what some people have pointed out... Is there a way to make my proof correct?

Comment: If I found one, it wouldn't be your proof.

Comment: Both the first and the last digit of $n$ have to be odd. If $n$ is not a multiple of $11$ and $n$ has an even number of digits, we get a contradiction from the fact that $n$ and $\bullet n$ have opposite remainders $\!\!\pmod{11}$ and $-1$ is not a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{11}$. Maybe this argument can be extended to other prime factors of repunits.

Comment: The very beginning of the proof can be fixed: both the first and last digits have to be $1$, since the other chances $(3,7),(9,9)$ do not lead to a first digit of $n\cdot\bullet n$ equal to $1$, but to a first digit in $\{2,3,8,9\}$. Maybe this can be used to perform some kind of induction on the length of the decimal representation of $n$.

Comment: Given that the first and last digit of $n$ are $1$, the length of $n\cdot\bullet n$ is odd, hence $n\cdot \bullet n\equiv 1\pmod{11}$, so the length of $n$ has to be odd.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that $n$ has $m+1$ digits: $n=\sum_{i=0}^{m}a_i10^{i}$, where $m\geq 1$. The product $P$ is given as follows:
\begin{align}
P&= \sum_{i=0}^{m}a_010^{i}\sum_{j=0}^{m}a_{m-j}10^{j} = \sum_{i,j=0}^m a_{i}a_{m-j}10^{i+j} \\
&= a_0a_m + 10(a_0a_{m-1}+a_1a_m)+\ldots+ 10^{2m-1}(a_0a_{m-1}+a_1a_m)+10^{2m}a_0a_m \hspace{3cm} (1)
\end{align}

We first note that the last digit of $P$ is same as the last digit of $a_0a_m$. So we have $(a_0,a_m)$ as either $(1,1),(3,7),(7,3)$, or $(9,9)$.

Next, we look at the range of $P$. Since $n$ has $m+1$ digits, we get the following:
\begin{equation}
10^{m}+1\leq n\leq 10^{m+1}-1\implies (10^{m}+1)^2\leq P\leq (10^{m+1}-1)^2 \implies 10^{2m}<P<10^{2m+2}.
\end{equation}
Thus, the number of digits in $P$ is either $2m+1$ or $2m+2$. So, we get
\begin{equation}
P = \sum_{k=0}^{2m}10^k=\frac{10^{2m+1}-1}{9}, \text{ or } P = \sum_{k=0}^{2m+1}10^k=\frac{10^{2m+2}-1}{9}.
\end{equation}
Also, (1) gives that
\begin{equation}
(10^{2m}+1)a_0a_m \leq P,
\end{equation}
where $(a_0,a_m)$ can be either $(1,1),(3,7),(7,3),$ or $(9,9)$
Hence, we have two cases corresponding to the two values of $P$:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
(10^{2m}+1)a_0a_m \leq \frac{10^{2m+1}-1}{9} \implies 9a_0a_m+1\leq 10^{2m}(10-9a_0a_m)\implies (a_0,a_m)=(1,1)\\
(10^{2m}+1)a_0a_m \leq \frac{10^{2m+2}-1}{9} \implies 9a_0a_m+1\leq 10^{2m}(100-9a_0a_m)\implies (a_0,a_m)=(1,1).
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Further, when $a_0,a_m=(1,1)$, we get that
\begin{equation}
P\leq (1\underset{m-1 \text{ times}}{\underbrace{99\ldots99}}1)^2 \leq (2.10^m)^2=4.10^{2m} < \frac{10^{2m+2}-1}{9}.
\end{equation}
Thus, we have only possible value for $P=\frac{10^{2m+1}-1}{9}$.

So, the problem reduces to finding integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{m-1}$ such that
\begin{align}
1 + 10(a_{m-1}+a_1)+\ldots+ 10^{2m-1}(a_{m-1}+a_1)+10^{2m} &= \frac{10^{2m+1}-1}{9}\\
\implies  (a_{m-1}+a_1)+\ldots+ 10^{2m-2}(a_{m-1}+a_1) &= \frac{10^{2m}-1}{9}
\end{align}

Next, we look at the last digit of $\frac{10^{2m}-1}{9}$, which is same as the digit of $a_{m-1}+a_1$. Since $0\leq a_{m-1}+a_{1}\leq 18$, we get that $a_{m-1}+a_{1}=1,11$. 
Moreover, we have
\begin{equation*}
\frac{10^{2m}-1}{9}\geq  (a_{m-1}+a_1)+ 10^{2m-2}(a_{m-1}+a_1)\implies (a_{m-1}+a_1) \geq \frac{10^{2m}-1}{9(1+10^{2m-2})}.
\end{equation*}
However, $\frac{10^{2m}-1}{9(1+10^{2m-2})}> 11$, for $m>2$. Hence, $m=1,2$.

When $m=1$, $(a_0,a_m)=(1,1)$ implies that $n=11$, which is not a solution.
Similarly, when $m=2$, $(a_0,a_m)=(1,1)$ and $a_1+a_{m-1}=1,11$ implies that $n=111$, which is also not a solution.

Hence, we conclude that there is **no solution** to the problem